# Running code between timesteps using scipy's solve_ivp

Tags: python, scipy

I'm transitioning my code from using scipy's odeint to scipy's solve_ivp. When using odeint I would use a while loop as follows:

```py
while solver.successful() : 
    solver.integrate(t_final, step=True)
    # do other operations
```

This method allowed me to store values that depended on the solutions after each timestep.

I'm now switching to using solve_ivp but not sure how to accomplish this functionality with the solve_ivp solver. Has anyone accomplished this functionality with solve_ivp?

Thanks!

Comment: What is # do other operations?  Is it something like `do_other_operation(t_solution ,y_solution)`?  If so, why not run this after the ode using `solve_ivp` with all the values of `t_solution` and `y_solution` instead of incrementally.

Answer (score 0):

I think i know what your trying to ask. I had a program that used solve_ivp to integrate between each time step individually, then used the values to calculate the values for the next iteration. (i.e. heat transfer coefficients, transport coefficients etc.) I used two nested for loops. The inner for loop calculates or completes the operations you need to at each step. Then save each value in a list or array and then the inner loop should terminate. The outer loop should only be used to feed time values and possibly reload necessary constants.

For example:

```
for i in range(start_value, end_value, time_step):
start_time = i
end_time = i + time_step
# load initial values and used most recent values
    for j in range(0, 1, 1):


    answer = solve_ivp(function,(start_time,end_time), [initial_values])
    # Save new values at the end of a list storing all calculated values
```

Say you have a system such as

1. d(Y1)/dt = a1*Y2 + Y1
2. d(Y2)/dt = a2*Y1 + Y2

and you want to solve it from t = 0, 10. With a 0.1 time step. Where a1 and a2 are values calculated or determined elsewhere. This code would work.

```
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



def a1(n):
       return 1E-10*math.exp(n)

def a2(n):
       return 2E-10*math.exp(n)

def rhs(t,y, *args):
       a1, a2 = args
       return [a1*y[1] + y[0],a2*y[0] + y[1]]

Y1 = [0.02]
Y2 = [0.01]
A1 = []
A2 = []
endtime = 10 
time_step = 0.1
times = np.linspace(0,endtime, int(endtime/time_step)+1)
tsymb = sp.symbols('t')
ysymb = sp.symbols('y')
for i in range(0,endtime,1):

       for j in range(0,int(1/time_step),1):
              tstart = i + j*time_step
              tend = i + j*time_step + time_step
              A1.append(a1(tstart/100))
              A2.append(a2(tstart/100))
              Y0 = [Y1[-1],Y2[-1]]
              args = [A1[-1],A2[-1]]
              answer = solve_ivp(lambda tsymb, ysymb : rhs(tsymb,ysymb, *args), (tstart,tend), Y0)
              Y1.append(answer.y[0][-1])
              Y2.append(answer.y[1][-1])

fig = plt.figure()
plt1 = plt.plot(times,Y1, label = "Y1")
plt2 = plt.plot(times,Y2, label = "Y2")
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Y Values')
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```